# Pluralization of an Plural Proper Noun (Organization)

Tags: proper-nouns, apostrophe

I work for the University of Southern California's USC Games department.

How would I indicate possessive ownership of items belonging to that department.

Is

> USC Games' student developers

correct? (Especially according to AP Style)

Comment: The AP style rule is quite clear on this point. From _The Associated Press Stylebook_ (2002): "**possessives** ... NOUNS PLURAL IN FORM, SINGULAR IN MEANING: Add only an apostrophe: _mathematics' rules_, _measles' effects_. ... Apply the same principle when a plural word occurs in the formal name of a singular entity: _General Motors' profits_, _the United States' wealth_.

Comment: How about knowing when to use "a" versus "an"? :)

Comment: To introduce "USC," we would use *an,* because we begin pronouncing the initialism by pronouncing the name of the letter *U,* which begins with a vowel sound: using IPA, /yu/.

Answer (score 1):

> USC Games' student developers

is a perfectly grammatical and standard phrase, conforming to AP style guidelines.

*USC Games* appears to be the name of a program at USC. It is also written *USCGames* on their own website: http://games.usc.edu/

The standard quoted by Sven Yargs in his comment is indeed clear on this point:

> From The Associated Press Stylebook (2002): "possessives ... NOUNS PLURAL IN FORM, SINGULAR IN MEANING: Add only an apostrophe: mathematics' rules, measles' effects. ... Apply the same principle when a plural word occurs in the formal name of a singular entity: General Motors' profits, the United States' wealth.

-- [Pluralization of an Plural Proper Noun (Organization)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104431/pluralization-of-an-plural-proper-noun-organization/107357#comment207180_104431)

Extracting directly from that statement, we get *USCGames' student developers* or *USC Games' student developers.*

Another example:

> According to the **U.S. State Department's International Religious Freedom Report** for 2012, in Turkey there are 90,000 Armenian Orthodox . . ..

Source information:

Date    2015
Publication information Winter2015, Vol. 50 Issue 1, p167-173. 7p.
Title   THE IMPORTANCE OF DIALOGUE IN TURKEY
Author  Cetinkaya, Kenan;
Source  ACAD: Journal of Ecumenical Studies

Search result on *State Department 's* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/

Answer (score -1):

Include the "department":  "The USC Games Department's student developers."

"Games," in this case, is being used as an adjective (describing the kind of "department"), and not as a plural noun.

It is the Department -- specifically, the Games Department-- which possesses student developers, not the "Games".

Comment: No, the brand name is literally USC Games. It isn't just the name of the department. The actual department is the Interactive Media and Games Division. USC Games is a brand (like Kelloggs)

http://Games.usc.edu

Comment: There is no basis for suggesting inclusion of the whole name of the department. This is like suggesting that someone say *The United States of America* instead of *The US* or *America.* These are often open choices, and when one or the other is preferred depends primarily or most often on the context of the communicative situation.